# Existing Android studio project import into Github. Push rejected?

Tags: android, git, github

I tried to follow this tutorial:
https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

But when I push it says 
Push rejected: Push to origin/master was rejected

I suspect is it the reason of remote add?
if my project path is https://github.com/myusername/projectname
My remote add should add github.com/myusername/projectname.git?

Comment: The push could have been rejected for a number of reasons, but the most probable perhaps is that other have made commits to the remote branch since the last time you pulled.  Do a `git fetch origin`, then type `git status` from your branch.

Comment: Have you *created* the repository on GitHub? https://github.com/ohyeslk/livemap_android does not exist on GitHub.

Comment: Yes I have, it is a private repo

Comment: You probably created the README or LICENSE while creating the repository. Use `git push --force origin master` from the Git Bash to make `git` forcefully push the latest commit to `origin/master`.

Comment: status show:   On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:

Comment: @EvilTak Thanks very much, I did create readme, and your code works!

Comment: Remember that when you use `push --force`, it will overwrite whatever you have on the remote branch. I don't recommend using it ever unless you're completely sure of what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if you inited the local git repository in your project's root directory.

Then check if you correctly added your remote origin.

Check the remotes:

```
git remote -v
```

If the existing remote origin is wrong, then change it:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myusername/projectname.git
```

If it's not existing, add it:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/projectname.git
```

Comment: You need to include the protocol: `https://github.com/ohyeslk/livemap_android.git`